# AWS Cognito sign-on in iOS: don't ask for phone #

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm going through the [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/tutorial-ios-aws-mobile-notes-setup.html) on integrating AWS with mobile apps.

The default sign up view controller has a field for the phone number. I made the email the only required field in the Cognito console. I also disabled sign-in with phone number. Is there a way to remove the phone number field from the sign-up VC?

[image]

Comment: After editing the Cognito form on the AWS hub, did you redownload the configuration file? I haven't used AWS in a while but that was an issue I had once

Comment: I am having the same issue and didn't manage to remove the Phone Number field either. I wonder if you managed to do it, and if so how.